# Remove \u00A0 character from a string

Tags: regex, vba, replace, special-characters

I have the following string in a cell:

[image]

I want to split the string into an array which contains only the textual word (such as 'CRMNegocios') without any bullets, new lines, etc...

To do it, I've wrote the below code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim stringsToCheck As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim stripped As String

    'Split cell value per vbLf
    stringsToCheck = Split(Cells(42, 10).Value, vbLf)
    MsgBox ("Total length of stringsToCheck is " & CStr(UBound(stringsToCheck)))

    'Remove special characters - for testing only, it will set the cell with the last value of the array
    For Each element In stringsToCheck
        stripped = GetStrippedText(CStr(element))
        Cells(42, 15) = stripped
    Next element


End Sub

Private Function GetStrippedText(txt As String) As String
    Dim regEx As Object

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    '\u0000-\u007F is for other special characters
    regEx.Pattern = "[\u25A0\u00A0\u0000-\u007F]"
    GetStrippedText = regEx.Replace(txt, "")

End Function
```

The bullet is removed (it is `\u25A0`) as expected, but i'm still left with the `\u00A0` characters before the textual word:

[image]

I've checked and the [regex is matching](https://regex101.com/r/KP1tF6/1), why it is not removed in the VBA ?

As mentioned in comments, original text in the cell:

```
■         CRMNegocios
■         GestiondeProyectos
■         Emblue
■         Videoconferencia
```

Text in test cell, after code run:

Videoconferencia

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to remove these non-word chars from the start of a string? I think you might just use `regEx.Pattern = "^\W+"` or, using your way, `regEx.Pattern = "^[\u25A0\u00A0\s]+"`. Note that `\u0000-\u007F` defines an ASCII table range and if you use it to replace, it will remove all ASCII letters, digits, all ASCII symbols from the string

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that does work. Can you please explain [in an answer, so i can accept :)] why my initial approach was not matching in VBA ? and setting `regEx.Global = True` caused everything to be replaced. Although it seemed matching is correct in [here](https://regex101.com/r/KP1tF6/1) - it should have just find the special chars and remove them, why do I have to pinpoint the `^` for start of string, what will happen if i want to remove special characters in any place in the string ?

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `"^[\u25A0\u00A0\s]+"` to remove all the standard whitespace, non-breaking spaces and the bullet points. It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\u25A0\u00A0\s]+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `\u25A0` - bullet points
  - `\u00A0` - non-breaking spaces
  - `\s` - `[ \r\t\n\f]` whitespace

Your regex is not matching globally, so after matching and removing the first bullet point, it stopped. Then, your regex also contains  `u0000-\u007F` range that defines all ASCII characters. If used as is, with `Replace`, it removes all ASCII letters, digits, all ASCII symbols from the string. That is why your text was removed when you added `.Global = True` to match all occurrences.

Note that if you deal with ASCII only texts, and you need to remove any non-word chars from the start of a string, you may use `regEx.Pattern = "^\W+"` (no need to set `.Global` to *True*).